# SSRS Reports for Project Server 2016

Tags: reporting-services, ms-project-server-2016

I need help to design Reports in SSRS for Project Server 2016.
Is there anyone to help in this regard.
I have connected to database and can see some view where I can extract the data, but I need proper way to follow for creating reports.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All you need to reach your goal is here maybe :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/create-a-basic-table-report-ssrs-tutorial